# PHP getting no response body

Tags: php, sql

Username and password values are being passed into my login php file and returning as a jsonResponse string. However the jsonResponse string that is being returning is empty?

```
<?php

# this file will return true or false depending if passed in username and password matcha user on the system.
ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);

$dbhost     = "localhost";
$dbname     = "example";
$dbuser     = "example";
$dbpass     = "example";

$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname",$dbuser,$dbpass);


    $data = array( $_POST["username"],$_POST["password"] );

    $stmt = $conn->prepare("Select * FROM example where username=?, password=?");   
    if(mysql_num_rows($stmt)>0)
    {
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($stmt);
        if($_POST["password"] == $row["password"])
        {
                  echo "loggedIn";    
        }
        else
        {
            echo "passwordNotValid"; alert
        }
    }
    else
      {
        echo "usernameNotValid"; 
      }

    if(!$stmt)
    {
    print_r($dbh->errorInfo());
    }

}

?>
```

Comment: Fix syntax errors first (run `php -l <filename>` to get them without executing the script)

Comment: you are mixing PDO and mysql_* functions???

Answer (score 1):

You have a lot of issues...

1. Remove the `alert` from that line

   `echo "passwordNotValid"; alert`
2. Close the quotes like shown

   `echo "usernameNotValid";`
3. Remove a `}` brace from the last line..

Apart from these issues... The (`mysql_*`) extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead,the `MySQLi` or `PDO_MySQL` extension should be used. Switching to `PreparedStatements` is even more better to ward off SQL Injection attacks !

Comment: Could you you show me an example of a better way than select * ?

Comment: `mysql_fetch_array`is ?

Comment: yes i know but he is connecting / prepare via PDO and fetching results via mysql_* functions

Comment: @user3268379, Why what is the problem with `SELECT *` ? Anyways you need to do that no matter `PDO` or `MySQLi`. First of all you need to switch to Pure PDO or MySQLi .. **You are mixing up the deprecated `mysql_*`functions and the `PDO`.**

Answer (score 1):

you are mixing mysql_* with PDO. Here is a complete example of PDO. you should use PDO like this.

```
 $dbhost     = "localhost";
$dbname     = "example";
$dbuser     = "example";
$dbpass     = "example";

$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname",$dbuser,$dbpass);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);



 $stmt = $conn->prepare("Select * FROM example where username=?, password=?");
```

use your username and password varaibles in bind params

```
$stmt ->bindParam(':username', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt ->bindParam(':password', $password, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt ->execute();



$result = $stmt ->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

and use $result in your page

Answer (score 0):

Syntax error in line

```
echo "usernameNotValid;
```

your code is most likely never executed.